# Why can't I select alternative Working Languages in Term Store Management Tool?

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, term-set, multilingual

I tried to create a multi-lingual term sets for a SharePoint Online Team Site following [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-multi-lingual-term-sets-d04098af-282b-45c3-97cb-59363042c1b3) guide. When trying to change the working language all options are grayed out and I can't select them. Same goes for the other locales option.
Under Site Settings > Language Settings the default language is English and all Alternative Languages are enabled. What do I have to do, to add another working language?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moritz, did you select the required Taxonomy group in left-hand side? And what is your account permission? You need to be a Term Store Administrator to change working language. Add your account in Term Store Administrators and refresh the page.